# Is it safe to make a ConcurrentBag as notifiable?

Tags: c#, concurrent-programming

I need to make a ConcurrentBag as notifable. I need to know that is it safe? Code for the class is

```
public class NotifiableConcurrentBag<T> : ConcurrentBag<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged where T : class
{
    public NotifiableConcurrentBag()
    {
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread == dispatcher.Thread)
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
            else
                dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
                }
                ));
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using method hiding: `public new void Add(T item) { ... }`. So, when the client code gets the reference to the instance of `NotifiableConcurrentBag<T>` as `ConcurrentBag<T>` the wrong version of `Add()` (for `ConcurrentBag<T>`) method will be called.

I would like to suggest you extracting the `IConcurrentBag<T>` interface.

```
public interface IConcurrentBag<T> : IProducerConsumerCollection<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
    bool TryPeek(out T result);
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}
```

Then introduce new extended interface `INotifiableConcurrentBag<T>` which actually supports `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface:

```
public interface INotifiableConcurrentBag<T> : IConcurrentBag<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged 
{
}
```

After that just implement `NotifiableConcurrentBag<T>` class (prefer composition over inheritance). Insert the notification logic instead of TODO markers.

```
public class NotifiableConcurrentBag<T> : INotifiableConcurrentBag<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> _concurrentBag;

    public NotifiableConcurrentBag()
    {
        _concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    }

    public NotifiableConcurrentBag(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<T>(collection);
    }

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)_concurrentBag).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable<T>

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An enumerator for the contents of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)_concurrentBag).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ICollection

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the elements of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/> to an <see cref="T:System.Array"/>, starting at a particular <see cref="T:System.Array"/> index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/>. The <see cref="T:System.Array"/> must have zero-based indexing. </param><param name="index">The zero-based index in <paramref name="array"/> at which copying begins. </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null. </exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is less than zero. </exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException"><paramref name="array"/> is multidimensional.-or- The number of elements in the source <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/> is greater than the available space from <paramref name="index"/> to the end of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.-or-The type of the source <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/> cannot be cast automatically to the type of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.</exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            ((ICollection)_concurrentBag).CopyTo(array, index);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    int ICollection.Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
            {
                return _concurrentBag.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an object that can be used to synchronize access to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An object that can be used to synchronize access to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)_concurrentBag).SyncRoot; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether access to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/> is synchronized (thread safe).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if access to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.ICollection"/> is synchronized (thread safe); otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)_concurrentBag).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IConcurrentBag<T>

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an object to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to be added to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>. The value can be a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) for reference types.</param>
    void IConcurrentBag<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            _concurrentBag.Add(item);
            // TODO: Implement notification!
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to return an object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> without removing it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if and object was returned successfully; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="result">When this method returns, <paramref name="result"/> contains an object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> or the default value of <paramref name="T"/> if the operation failed.</param>
    bool IConcurrentBag<T>.TryPeek(out T result)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            return _concurrentBag.TryPeek(out result);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> is empty.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> is empty; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    bool IConcurrentBag<T>.IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
            {
                return _concurrentBag.IsEmpty;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IProducerConsumerCollection<T>

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to remove and return an object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if an object was removed successfully; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="result">When this method returns, <paramref name="result"/> contains the object removed from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> or the default value of <paramref name="T"/> if the bag is empty.</param>
    bool IProducerConsumerCollection<T>.TryTake(out T result)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            bool takeResult = _concurrentBag.TryTake(out result);
            if (takeResult)
            {
                // TODO: Implement notification!
            }
            return takeResult;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> elements to an existing one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/>, starting at the specified array index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>. The <see cref="T:System.Array"/> must have zero-based indexing.</param><param name="index">The zero-based index in <paramref name="array"/> at which copying begins.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is less than zero.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException"><paramref name="index"/> is equal to or greater than the length of the <paramref name="array"/> -or- the number of elements in the source <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> is greater than the available space from <paramref name="index"/> to the end of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.</exception>
    void IProducerConsumerCollection<T>.CopyTo(T[] array, int index)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            _concurrentBag.CopyTo(array, index);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/> elements to a new array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A new array containing a snapshot of elements copied from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    T[] IProducerConsumerCollection<T>.ToArray()
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            return _concurrentBag.ToArray();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to add an object to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.IProducerConsumerCollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the object was added successfully; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Concurrent.IProducerConsumerCollection`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The <paramref name="item"/> was invalid for this collection.</exception>
    bool IProducerConsumerCollection<T>.TryAdd(T item)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)this).SyncRoot)
        {
            bool addResult = ((IProducerConsumerCollection<T>)_concurrentBag).TryAdd(item);
            if (addResult)
            {
                // TODO: Implement notification!
            }
            return addResult;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats a nice approach. I will use it.

Comment: Locking on ConcurrentBag.SyncRoot will throw a NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 2):

Basically no, this approach is not safe: thread-safety issues aside (I did not assess its thread-safety), it leaves many possibilities to add items to the collection without actually invoking the notification. Consider the following simpler implementation:

```
public class NotifiableConcurrentBag<T> : ConcurrentBag<T> where T : class {
    public int CountOfAdditions { get; set; }

    public new void Add(T item) {
        base.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine("Overloaded!");
        CountOfAdditions++;
    }   
}
```

Now someone writes a tricky code that uses this collection not only as a `NotifiableConcurrentBag`, but also as simply `ConcurrentBag` (inherited) and, even worse, `IProducerConsumerCollection` (implemented through inherited `ConcurrentBag`):

```
NotifiableConcurrentBag<string> s = new NotifiableConcurrentBag<string>();
Console.WriteLine("CHANGE --->");
s.Add("s");

ConcurrentBag<string> o = (ConcurrentBag<string>) s;
Console.WriteLine("CHANGE --->");
o.Add("s");

IProducerConsumerCollection<string> col = (IProducerConsumerCollection<string>) s;
Console.WriteLine("CHANGE --->");
col.TryAdd("s");

Console.WriteLine("Overloaded called {0} times", s.CountOfAdditions);
Console.WriteLine("In fact collection has {0} items", s.Count);
```

The output of this program is the following:

```
CHANGE --->
Overloaded!
CHANGE --->
CHANGE --->
Overloaded called 1 times
In fact collection has 3 items
```

This means that your implementation would have left two additions without any notifications. For the implementation to be genuinely safe, you would probably need to wrap the ConcurrentBag rather than inherit it, and implement the interfaces that you need in such a fashion that the notification is always called.

Comment: Correct.. but is that only problem? means if i have another method say AddNew and I always call AddNew then there is no issue?

Comment: As long as you ensure that the correct method is called, of course, there seems to be no problem. But how do you ensure this? Consider what would happen if you pass this collection to a third-party library accepting `IProducerConsumerCollection` or just `ConcurrentBag` directly? You would never receive notifications then if the third-party library modifies the collection, as the library is certainly not aware of your notification features. Hence, it seems to be a highly risky venture -- to rely just on the fact that you use only the correct method. Others may not know about this.