# Databinding to a BlockingCollection

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to implement the following requirements (C# 4.0);

- One "producer" (on the UI thread - driven by user action) which submits upload requests
- A `ListView` control which is databound to the collection of pending upload requests
- One consumer which process the requests (FIFO), and keeps the UI up-to-date as items status' update, or the request is fulfilled.

So far, I haven't been able to work out how to do the above without using two collections, as follows;

```
public void AddUploadRequest(UploadRequest uploadRequest)
{
    this.UploadRequests.Add(uploadRequest);
    this.uploadRequestsBlocking.Add(uploadRequest);
}
```

... where `UploadRequests` is an `ObservableCollection<UploadRequest>` and `uploadRequestsBlocking` is a `BlockingCollection<UploadRequest>`

The full code can be found here; http://pastebin.com/620EqaY5 (ignore the gross injection of Dispatcher - this is just prototype code so far)

I notify my UI of updates as follows;

```
this.dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.UploadRequests.Remove(uploadRequest));
```

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality? Or, more importantly, are there any serious drawbacks to this approach?

One possible extension I was considering was to have multiple consumers, by using `Parallel.ForEach` over `GetConsumingPartitioner` (based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) example). Would anything about the current approach make this unsuitable? It does work OK, but I'm not 100% confident that I haven't committed some major threading faux-pas somewhere along the way.

Comment: Are you using C# 5.0?

Comment: No... I'm using C#4.0 - I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main (only) reason that you can't just databind to the BlockingCollection is that it does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged, so the UI would not get updated when a request is added / removed. That said, there are [BlockingCollection wrappers around on the net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134141/is-it-safe-to-make-a-concurrentbag-as-notifiable) that implement INotifyCollectionChanged. Or you could instead expose a CollectionView for the BlockingCollection and instead of dispatching a remove from an ObservableCollection, just dispatch a Refresh of the CollectionView.

```
    public ICollectionView UploadRequestsView {get;set;}

    public UploadRequester(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;           
        this.uploadRequestsBlocking = new BlockingCollection<UploadRequest>();

        UploadRequestsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(uploadRequestsBlocking);

        this.consumerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ConsumeUploadRequests);
    }

    public void AddUploadRequest(UploadRequest uploadRequest)
    {
        uploadRequestsBlocking.Add(uploadRequest);
        UploadRequestsView.Refresh()
    }

    private void ConsumeUploadRequests()
    {
        foreach (var uploadRequest in this.uploadRequestsBlocking.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            uploadRequest.Status = "Uploading...";

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            uploadRequest.Status = "Successfully uploaded";

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            dispatcher.Invoke(() => UploadRequestsView.Refresh());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that I would need to call UploadRequestsView.Refresh() inside the "AddUploadRequest" call (and so use the dispatcher on every addition)?

Comment: Thanks Andrew - this approach seems to work well for my use case.

Comment: I'm glad this helps - One thing to keep in mind is that if you have a large number of items and additions / removals happening quickly, this can hang the UI more readily than a Collection Change notification since the whole list is refreshed rather than a single item. One way to avoid this is to throttle the refresh to only occur every x milliseconds when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `TPL` and no need for injecting the `Dispatcher` since `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will give me the current `Dispatcher` of the `MainUI` thread.

```
public class UploadRequestProcessor
{
        public ObservableCollection<UploadRequest> UploadRequests { get; private set; }
        private readonly BlockingCollection<UploadRequest> uploadRequestsBlocking;
        private Task consumerTask;

        public UploadRequester()
        {
                this.UploadRequests = new ObservableCollection<UploadRequest>();
                this.uploadRequestsBlocking = new BlockingCollection<UploadRequest>();
                this.consumerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ConsumeUploadRequests).ContinueWith(nextTask => RemoveUploadRequests(nextTask.Result as BlockingCollection<UploadRequest>), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        public void AddUploadRequest(UploadRequest uploadRequest)
        {
                this.UploadRequests.Add(uploadRequest);
                this.uploadRequestsBlocking.Add(uploadRequest);
        }

        private void ConsumeUploadRequests()
        {
            var requestsToRemove = new BlockingCollection<UploadRequest>();
                foreach (var uploadRequest in this.uploadRequestsBlocking.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                        uploadRequest.Status = "Uploading...";

                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        uploadRequest.Status = "Successfully uploaded";

                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        requestsToRemove.Add(uploadRequest);

                }
            return requestsToRemove;
        }

        private void RemoveUploadRequests(BlockingCollection<UploadRequest> requestsToRemove)
        {
            foreach(var request in requestsToRemove)
            {
                UploadRequests.Remove(request);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I never actually mark my BlockingCollection as complete, so "requestsToRemove" is never returned. Thanks for the SynchronizationContext tip though - will look at incorporating that.